# localhost:8000 error in IE 11

Tags: python

I have problem opening http://localhost:8000 when opening my python script.
I was having this problem on Windows 7. I was just opening the forum.py file with python on my windows machine. This gave the correct looking "Serving HTTP on port 8000..." message but it wasn't working when I navigated to http://localhost:8000. I don't exactly know why but you have to run the forum.py from within the VM, not from windows. So to do this, once you ssh into the VM, navigate to 'cd vagrant/forum' and do an 'ls' to find the forum.py file. run 'python forum.py' here and it should start up. Once I did it from within the VM I was able to get it open in my browser.

I tried to change the host number to 8080 (the second configuration in vagrantfile) or even substituting 8000 in vagrantfile and forum.py with 3456 and opening localhost:3456, but then I get the following message:

A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.

I need your help please!

Comment: I just switch the connection to another port in the forum.py code to port 8190 and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you just switch the connection to another port in the forum.py code it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just switch the connection to another port in the forum.py code to port 8190 and it seems to be working